# Logging only written on old [filename].1 log files

Tags: debian, logging, syslog, debian-wheezy

My log is not written on the correct log file for example `syslog, mail.log, mysql.log, auth.log` but for some reason the latest event are written on these old log files `syslog.1, auth.log.1, mail.log.1` . They are huge files because of their previous data.

I can see latest event on November 4th written correctly in `[filename].1` file. What is happening here? Please help and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason logging stop after working without a problem. Here is the solution : https://serverfault.com/a/545623/109483

Unlike the poster there, I'm not upgrading from `Squeeze` because I did a fresh installation of `Wheezy` but still had the same problem. Interestingly the solution is similar.

Thanks.